# How can I get all the public property values of a 'last descendant' object in php?

Tags: php, oop

The code below makes this easier to explain :

```
<?php

class a
{
    public $dog = 'woof';
    public $cat = 'miaow';
    private $zebra = '??';
}                 

class b extends a
{
    protected $snake = 'hiss';
    public $owl = 'hoot';
    public $bird = 'tweet';
}

$test = new b();

print_r(get_object_vars($test));
```

Currently this returns:

```
Array
(
    [owl] => hoot
    [bird] => tweet
    [dog] => woof
    [cat] => miaow
)
```

what can I do to find properties that were only defined or set in class b (eg just owl and bird)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ReflectionObject` for this:

```
$test = new b();

$props = array();
$class = new ReflectionObject($test);
foreach($class->getProperties() as $p) {
    if($p->getDeclaringClass()->name === 'b') {
        $p->setAccessible(TRUE);
        $props[$p->name] = $p->getValue($test);
    }
}

print_r($props);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [snake] => hiss
    [owl] => hoot
    [bird] => tweet
)
```

`getProperties()` will return all properties of the class. I'm using `$p->getDeclaringClass()` afterwards to check if the declaring class is `b`

---

Additionally this can be generalized to a function:

```
function get_declared_object_vars($object) {
    $props = array();
    $class = new ReflectionObject($object);
    foreach($class->getProperties() as $p) {
        $p->setAccessible(TRUE);
        if($p->getDeclaringClass()->name === get_class($object)) {
            $props[$p->name] = $p->getValue($object);
        }   
    }   

    return $props;
}

print_r(get_declared_object_vars($test));
```

Comment: Thanks, it turned out I didn't need to do this in the end, but it's still a very useful concept :)